# implement multiple pipes in c

Tags: operating-system, pipe

I'm trying to implement multiple pipes in c++. Namely, I want to write a program to simulate the execution of, for example, ls -l | head -n 10 | wc -l.

The code works all fine. But after all the commands are executed correctly, I need to *hit enter* to return to the command line. I guess I have to "wait()" somewhere

Here is the code I'm having now.

```
using namespace std; 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

int pid;
int fd[4];

pipe(fd + 0); // pipe between the 1st and 2nd command
pipe(fd + 2); // pipe between the 2nd and 3rd command

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ // 3 commands

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){// child process

        if( i == 0 ){// first command

            char *arg[10];
            arg[0] = "ls";
            arg[1] = NULL;

            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1], 1);
            execvp(arg[0], arg);
        }
        else if( i == 1){// second command

            char *arg[10];
            arg[0] = "head";
            arg[1] = "-n1";
            arg[2] = NULL;

            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            dup2(fd[3], 1);
            execvp(arg[0], arg);
        }
        else if( i== 2){// third command

            char *arg[10];
            arg[0] = "wc";
            arg[1] = "-l";
            arg[2] = NULL;

            close(fd[3]);
            dup2(fd[2], 0);
            execvp(arg[0], arg);

        }

    }

    else{// parent
    }

}

}
```

I think I have gone thru all posts similar to mine, but still can't figure this out.

Can anyone help?